# SourceTree - How to undo Pushed commits

Tags: version-control, datasource, atlassian-sourcetree

Using Source Tree 1.9, there are 5 commits e.g. a-b-c-d-e that are pushed to develop branch and I want to undo pushed commits for "c".

1. will that affect other commits - a,b,d,e.
2. How to undo commit done for "c" without affecting other commits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot undo a pushed commit.

But you can use the reverse commit functionality (right click on the commit and select Reverse Commit). This feature adds another commit on top which is the reverse of the one you selected.

For example:

- If you added a line of code, this removes it
- If you created a file, this deletes it
- If you deleted a file, this restores it

Comment: But will that affect other commits? as my committed changes are in between of other commits

Comment: This adds a commit on top of the others reverting all the changes you made in the selected commit. You cannot modify a commit.

Comment: Can you please help me in below issue :

Comment: code is in VSTS 2015, where code is able to find excel file path name, excel file name and excel sheet name.

But when it comes to "dbAdapter.Fill(table);", exception is thrown as Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Data.dll

Additional information: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Comment: You need to open another question for that and add tags to define what language and framework you are using